# If you roll a die 5 times, what is the probability that you roll at least one five?

Tags: probability

> If you roll a die 5 times, what is the probability that you roll at least one five.

Is it p(1/5), or do I need to do a bionomcdf, I'm confused.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697433/a-family-has-three-children-what-is-the-probability-that-at-least-one-of-them-i

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of fives. You want $\Pr(X\ge 1)$. This is $\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\cdots+\Pr(X=5)$. You **could** calculate them all and add up, using the binomial distribution. For example, $\Pr(X=2)=\binom{5}{2}(1/5)^2(5/6)^3$. However, the procedure used in the current answer is **far** quicker.

Comment: If you encounter expressions like 'at least' or 'at most' in the event, then see that as an encouragement to look at *the complement of the event*. Its probability is (almost) always much easyer to calculate.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Probability of no five in $5$ rolling is $$\left(\frac56\right)^5$$

Probability of at least one five $=1-$ Probability of no five