# A problem in mathematics is given to $3$ students whose chances of solving it are $\frac13,\frac14,\frac15$

Tags: probability

> A problem in mathematics is given to $3$ students whose chances of solving it are $ \frac13,\frac14,\frac15 $. What is the probability that the problem is solved?

Shouldn't the probability of the problem being solved be $\frac13×\frac14×\frac15=\frac1{60}$.
But the answer given is $\frac35$. 
Please explain why I am wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697433/a-family-has-three-children-what-is-the-probability-that-at-least-one-of-them-i

Answer (score 5):

You calculated the probability that *all three* solve it.

The probability that *none* solve it is $\frac23×\frac34×\frac45=\frac25$, and the probability that *at least one* does (the question asks for this) is the complement, or $\frac35$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ be the events of solving the problem and $\overline{A},\overline{B},\overline{C}$ be the events of not solving the problem.

We have $P(A)=\dfrac13,P(B)=\dfrac14,P(C)=\dfrac15$

$P(\overline{A})=\dfrac23,P(\overline{B})=\dfrac34,P(\overline{C})=\dfrac45$

$P(\mbox{ none solves the problem})=P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\cap\overline{C})$

$=\dfrac23\times\dfrac34\times\dfrac45=\dfrac25$

Therefore,

$P(\mbox{ the problem will be solved})=1-P(\mbox{ none solves the problem})$

$$1-\dfrac25=\dfrac35$$